# How to handle MIDI NPRN data on controller startup

Tags: midi, midi-instrument, midi-interface

I have been approached to design a MIDI interface for a new instrument. It will use MIDI USB and I have the embedded MCU running a basic MIDI USB stack.

Many of the instrument's parameters need to be under control of a MIDI controller, however, the types and ranges of the parameters do not fit into the well-defined MIDI CC messages.

The approach we are following is to use Non-Registered Parameter Number messages to read/write the instruments parameters.

My question relates to how the controller acquires the current state of the instrument's parameters for display to the user when it starts up. I have read and reread the documents; however, I do not see any method for doing this, other than, reading each control one-by-one.

Is my conclusion correct or is there a better way for the controller to get the current state of the instrument parameters upon startup?

Answer (score 0):

The Stack overflow system prompted with the following question; this answers my question:

[How to get a current state of a midi device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660770/how-to-get-a-current-state-of-a-midi-device?rq=2)